# Log4j Print Extended Class Name

Tags: java, spring, log4j

How I can log the name of extended class? I want "FTSControl" written instead of "Control".

```
public abstract class Control {   
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());   
}

@Component
public class FTSControl extends Control { 

}

<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p - %C{1}:%m%n" />
</layout>
```

**Output:**

```
09.01.2015 15:58:00.006 WARN  - Control: No files found! Hash:-844390824
```

I have also point out sometinh that,

Although same logger instance is used,  log.info() invocation in a method of Control and FTSControl print its own class name. I mean

*logger.info() in  a method of **FTSControl** prints*

```
09.01.2015 15:58:00.006 WARN  - FTSControl : No files found! Hash:-844390824
```

*logger.info() in  a method of **Control** prints*

```
09.01.2015 15:58:00.006 WARN  - Control: No files found! Hash:-844390824
```

**//Update  Complete Example**

```
package com.log;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;

import com.log.abstracttest.ControlAbs;
import com.log.abstracttest.ImosControl;


public class LogMainTest {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("console");

    public  LogMainTest(){
        DOMConfigurator.configure(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("log4j.xml"));
        logger.info("Initializing...");

        ImosControl control = new ImosControl();
        control.print();
        control.printAll();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LogMainTest();

    }


}


package com.log.abstracttest;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public abstract class ControlAbs {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public void print(){
        logger.info(" print");
    }

}


package com.log.abstracttest;

public class ImosControl extends ControlAbs {

    public void printAll(){
        logger.info("printAll");
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
10.01.2015 05:38:43.497 INFO  - LogMainTest:Initializing...
10.01.2015 05:38:43.502 INFO  - ControlAbs: print
10.01.2015 05:38:43.503 INFO  - ImosControl:printAll
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed my ConversionPattern as following. from C ->c

```
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p - [%c{1}]:%m%n" />
```

**Conversion Character  Meaning**

**c**   Used to output the category of the logging event. For example, for the category name "a.b.c" the pattern %c{2} will output "b.c".

**C**   Used to output the fully qualified class name of the caller issuing the logging request. For example, for the class name "org.apache.xyz.SomeClass", the pattern %C{1} will output "SomeClass".

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());` in the abstract class with

```
protected final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

That way you are going to get the instanced class name in the log if you use something like `logger.info("test")` inside `FTSControl`

Comment: I have updated the question, pls look at the end of question.

Answer (score 0):

I would instead suggest to have a 'private static final' instance for Logger in each class and use that along with 'C'. That way the logger is available for static methods to be used as well and the class logged from can be more confidently identified.

```
public class FTSControl extends Control { 
    private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(FTSControl.class);
}
```

Changing the pattern to print the category rather than the calling class is a 'global' change and may lead to surprises.

Comment: in that case methods in parent class (Control) use its own logger instance and causes to print Control as a Class name instead of that of FTControl.So pls look at my answer below. It is more flexible and fits OOD.

Comment: My focus was for scenarios involving static methods in combination with using category in the logging pattern, in which case it would be simpler to have the class being called from. But I guess that scenario may never occur. (Eg: A base class and a sub class with the same static methods).